# How to increase the wss_logging database retention period

Tags: 2010, logging, uls

how to increase the wss_logging database retention period to store uls log files from default 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following MSDN article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manhar/2012/04/17/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-logging-database-or-how-to-purge-the-old-data-from-logging-database/ it will answer your question. The title says how to decrease the size of the logging database, but the article describes how to change the retention periods.

An example command:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Set-SPUsageDefinition -Identity ”Page Requests” -DaysRetained 3
```

This will set retention period to 3 days for "Page Requests":

[image]